# How to go to a specific external URL from your API using Django?

Tags: python, django, api

I being new to Django am learning how to go to an external URL from my API, so I made a project, and in that project I made an app like 'linker' and in the views of app I wrote this code:

```
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-                                                     
  from __future__ import unicode_literals                                     
  import urllib3                                                              
  from django.shortcuts import render                                         
  from django.http import HttpResponse                                        
  # Create your views here.                                                   

  def index(request):                                                         
     http = urllib3.PoolManager()                                            
     r = http.request('GET', 'www.google.com')                               
     return HttpResponse(r)
```

Now this is the views.py, is the code right?

Comment: Will the 'redirect' work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need urllib3.PoolManager() to make a redirect.
Use the redirect Django shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request):
    return redirect('https://duckduckgo.com/')
```

Comment: Thanks, also I was wondering if I am making the backend and the frontend guys are giving a search term, can I use the term with url and how?